# Change an Insert statement to an update statement in PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making an Android app that connects to a database online and lets the user edit the database from the application, I'm new to PHP and MySql but from my research I think I  should be using an UPDATE statement, I've written the code below to register new users on the site from a tutorial, but I'd like to change the INSERT statement to an UPDATE statement so that instead of registering a new user, the App updates existing data that I have entered in PHPMYADMIN, could someone show me how to do this? Also, if you require the code for the app mention it in the comments and I'll add it to the question, I don't want to post too much unneccessary code. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
    require "conn.php";

    $patient_name = $_POST["patient_name"];
    $check_in_date = $_POST["check_in_date"];
    $room_number = $_POST["room_number"];
    $bed_number = $_POST["bed_number"];
    $notes = $_POST["notes"];

    $mysql_qry = "insert into patients(patient_name, check_in_date, room_number, bed_number, notes) values ('$patient_name', '$check_in_date', '$room_number', '$bed_number', '$notes')";

    if($conn->query($mysql_qry) === TRUE) {
        echo "Insert successful";
    }
    else{
        echo "Error: " . $mysql_qry . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
    $conn->close();
?>
```

**EDIT**

The fixed code is below, it now updates records already in the database rather than adding new data.

```
<?php
    require "conn.php";

    $patient_name = $_POST["patient_name"];
    $check_in_date = $_POST["check_in_date"];
    $room_number = $_POST["room_number"];
    $bed_number = $_POST["bed_number"];
    $notes = $_POST["notes"];

    $mysql_qry = "UPDATE patients SET notes='$notes' WHERE patient_name='$patient_name'";

    if($conn->query($mysql_qry) === TRUE) {
        echo "Insert successful";
    }
    else{
        echo "Error: " . $mysql_qry . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
    $conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: You should look into building a small API that you can access for the two different objective you are looking to do.  One would be a put request and one would be a patch request.

Comment: [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp)

Comment: The above code presents a serious security flaw  - you are inserting `$_POST` values directly into the database without filtering them first. This will expose your database to SQL injections.

Comment: Your question too complex and too easy for the site. At first, read tutorial https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/index.htm After read abut SQL https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp P.S. For production code Prepared Statements for DB requests are preferred.

Comment: @YoavKadosh It doesn't need to be secure, it's only for a college project, functionality is the key thing here. Is it as simple as changing my current code to the code from the W3Schools link above?

Comment: @VitaliyPro 'too complex and too easy', I'm sorry I don't follow you. Thank you for the links though, I'll look at them

Answer (score 2):

first of all this PHP code is vulnerable to sql injection you should, no need to update your code to use either [mysqli prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [PDO prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

secondly the easiest way I know you accomplish your goal would make a unique constraint on some columns and then use a mysql feature `ON DUPLICATE UPDATE`

for this example I'll assume that the unique fields determining an update instead of an insert are `patient_name`, `check_in_date`, `room_number`, and `bed_number` (in case john smith was in the same room as john smith in seprate beds) the query to update the table would be like this

```
ALTER TABLE `patients` ADD UNIQUE `unique_index`(`patient_name`, `check_in_date`, `room_number`, `bed_number`);
```

so now to address the sql injection bit and the query, I'll update the example to use `mysqli statement` and will assume `patient_name` and `notes` are strings (varchar/nvarchar), `room_number` and `bed_number` are integers, and `check_in_date` is a date

**Edit** My original answer had a syntax error in the query and also passing variables to the prepared statement below is the updated answer

```
$mysqliConn = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "mydatabase");

$stmt = $mysqliConn->prepare("insert into patients
    (patient_name, check_in_date, room_number, bed_number, notes) 
    values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE notes=values(notes)");

$patient_name = $_POST["patient_name"];
$check_in_date = $_POST["check_in_date"];
$room_number = $_POST["room_number"];
$bed_number = $_POST["bed_number"];
$notes = $_POST["notes"];

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sdiis", 
    $patient_name, $check_in_date, $room_number, $bed_number, $notes);
```

hope this helps

**Edit**
Regarding the unique key, a unique key means that all fields in the unique key have to be unique when combined so for the example above

if record 1 is
patient_name, check_in_date, room_number, bed_number, notes
'john smith', '3/1/2017'    , 413        , 2         , 'patient is sick'
and record two is
'jane doe'  , '3/1/2017'    , 413        , 2         , 'patient has wound'

these two records will note be duplicates with the above constraint but if you do need to change the constraint you can do the following

DROP the Constraint

```
ALTER TABLE `patients` DROP INDEX `unique_index`;
```

Then recreate the constraint like this

```
ALTER TABLE `patients` ADD UNIQUE `unique_index`(`patient_name`, `check_in_date`, `room_number`);
```

also if you named your constraint something other than `unique_index` you can find the key_name by running the following

```
SHOW INDEX FROM `patients`;
```

the name will be in the `key_name` column

additionally you may want to alter the last line of the query to be this in your php if you change the unique constraint so you can change bed number

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE bed_number=values(bed_number), notes=values(notes)
```

Comment: Just referring to the first part of your answer, there is already a unique identifier column called 'ID' in the database that is auto incremented, so the first person registered is 1, second is 2 and so on. Thanks for the detailed answer!

Comment: a unique identifier or a primary key is fine, what the unique constraint would prevent from inserting duplicate records and enforce it at a database level, so if you try to update the notes for a patient instead of inserting the exact same record with different notes it would update the existing notes.

Comment: Okay thanks. So should the code in my original question be as follows: $MySQL_qry = "ALTER TABLE `patients` ADD UNIQUE `unique_index`(`patient_name`, `check_in_date`, `room_number`, `bed_number`);" 
and remove the line: $mysql_qry = "insert into patients(patient_name, check_in_date, room_number, bed_number, notes) values ('$patient_name', '$check_in_date', '$room_number', '$bed_number', '$notes')"; ?

Comment: no the alter query would be something you would run one time, while it could be run in php it would be easier to run it once in `PHPAdmin` since you mentioned you're using it

Comment: Oh okay thanks, I'll run that in PHPMyAdmin now and then do I just change the insert statement to an update statement?

Comment: in my proposed solution, you would leave it an `INSERT` statement but add the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` portion this way if the record doesn't exist it will be created but if it does exist it will be updated.

Comment: Hi, I managed the first part and those fields are now unique, but do you know how I would alter the code so that the rows are being updated rather than inserted? I get an error saying it is a duplicate entry and that I cannot add it. Shall I add the Java code from the app to my original question or is it irrelevant to what I am asking?

Comment: Also, after testing out the PHP I've discovered that 'bed number' is not unique as I can have two patients in the same bed at the same time. How can I amend this? Thanks

Comment: Hi, I've updated the code in the question showing my entire original file as well as what you told me to add, when I run your code I'm presented with the error message 'Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference'. Thanks for the help so far and sorry for all the questions but could you show me where I am going wrong? Thanks

Comment: I've corrected the answer so it should address your additional comments, and correct the error you're getting

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `REPLACE INTO`, then you don't have to change the SQL statement. Let MySQL do the work for you.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html

```
<?php
require "conn.php";

$patient_name = $_POST["patient_name"];
$check_in_date = $_POST["check_in_date"];
$room_number = $_POST["room_number"];
$bed_number = $_POST["bed_number"];
$notes = $_POST["notes"];

$mysql_qry = "REPLACE INTO patients(patient_name, check_in_date, room_number, bed_number, notes) VALUES ('$patient_name', '$check_in_date', '$room_number', '$bed_number', '$notes')";

if($conn->query($mysql_qry) === TRUE) {
    echo "Insert successful";
}
else{
    echo "Error: " . $mysql_qry . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
$conn->close();
```

Also, you should really take a look at using PDO with prepared statements and parameters.

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was looking for a small function that converts an INSERT MySQL query to an UPDATE query. So maybe other people were looking for the same and I think this is what the original poster was looking for aswell... I couldnt find any so I made this simple function which works for my needs, ofcourse you will have to make sure your original query is safe from MySQL injection.

It will convert

> INSERT INTO `aaa` (bbb, ccc) VALUES ('111', '222')

to

> UPDATE `aaa` SET ccc='222' WHERE bbb='111'

Use the 2nd variable ($iColumn) to identify the WHERE statement.

```
function convertInsertToUpdate($sQuery, $iColumn = 1) {
$sNewQuery = "";
$iPos = strpos($sQuery, ' (');
$sTmpTable = substr($sQuery, 0, $iPos);
$iPos = strpos($sTmpTable, 'INSERT INTO ');
$sTmpTable = substr($sTmpTable, $iPos+12);
$iPos = strpos($sQuery, ') VALUES (');
$sTmpValues = substr($sQuery, $iPos+10);
$iPos = strrpos($sTmpValues, ')');
$sTmpValues = substr($sTmpValues, 0, $iPos);
$iPos = strpos($sQuery, '(');
$sTmpColumns = substr($sQuery, $iPos+1);
$iPos = strpos($sTmpColumns, ') VALUES (');
$sTmpColumns = substr($sTmpColumns, 0, $iPos);

$aColumns = explode(', ', $sTmpColumns);
$aValues = explode(', ', $sTmpValues);

if (count($aColumns)>0 && count($aColumns) == count($aValues) && $iColumn < (count($aValues)+1)) {
    $sNewQuery = "UPDATE ".$sTmpTable." SET";
    $sTmpWhere = "";
    $bNotFirst = false;
    $iX = 0;
    while ($iX<count($aColumns)) {
        if ($iColumn == ($iX+1)) {
            $sTmpWhere = " WHERE ". $aColumns[$iX]."=".$aValues[$iX];
            $iX++;
            continue;
        }
        if ($bNotFirst) {
            $sNewQuery .= ",";
        }
        $sNewQuery .= " ".$aColumns[$iX]."=".$aValues[$iX];
        $bNotFirst = true;
        $iX++;
    }
    $sNewQuery .= $sTmpWhere;
}
return $sNewQuery;
}
```